# Is it possible to figure out caller context in apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

I am trying to set a field in an apex trigger iff the dml is triggered from a flow. I tried Quiddity but the context is SYNCHRONOUS. I was hoping there would be a way to differentiate between record page manual field update DML from flow triggered DML.

Comment: I am surprised the Quiddity is a single value here, but if that's what you found, ignore the suggestion.

Comment: @PhilW Yeah, both scenarios, flow and record page dmls, were resulting in the SYNCHRONOUS context. Which makes sense just because it's the catch all value and the only other closest value is INVOCABLE_ACTION, but that might just be exclusively for invocable actions. 

I did notice that I could infer caller context from the debug logs but not sure if there's an equivalent version I could get a hold off mid execution of apex logic. I tried looking at getStackTrace on a custom exception but that only returns the stack trace for the trigger entry and on and nothing prior to that.